# Is it possible to move a simple .exe based calculator tool to cloud for multi-users?

Tags: azure, cloud

A few years back, we had a programmer create a type of calculator for use in the audio industry. It was created/compiled in C - and is an .exe we offer for free download. once a user downloads it, they can run it locally.

Our goal is to move that application/calculator to the "cloud" where any user can hypothetically visit a URL, and the calculator is there, running, and ready for user interaction by multiple users.

- Is what I describe possible?
- Will I need Azure?
- What exactly in Azure will I need (i.e. which products/resources)?
- Do I need to use the compiled/decompiled version?
- Will we need to change any code in the .exe to make this work?
- What do I not know that I should know?

I sincerely appreciate any and all input from those that are probably reading this and fully understanding the simplicity of it while I struggle to wrap my head around it.

Thank you!

@Alex, Thank you so much for the response. I apologize I was late getting back to you - have 4 kiddos home - I am actually not sure how to answer that fully. Here is a link to the freely downloadable file we offer to anyone and everyone - it does require an email, but that is just for notifications when the version is updated. https://caf.prosoundtraining.com/verify/ and here is the home page of the site: https://caf.prosoundtraining.com - It works by the user downloading the program (which is what we would like to move to the cloud), and then inputing various values for determining what watt amplifier to use based on speaker selection, length of cables, distance of audience from speakers, etc. basically several calculation tools like that, and then the main program that allows users to visualize amplifier performance via running signal tests through the amplifier. Once a user downloads the program, the calculators (which are separate in the decompiled version I have), they can choose to just use the calculators, or the complete program.

Comment: This a little too vague of a description .... How does it currently work?

Comment: Also, in addition to above edit - please see here: https://caf.prosoundtraining.com/about-amplifiers/ and look at the last video - "Low-Z Calculator Overview" that may help - thank you!!

Comment: Look, this is a website about programming questions and answers. Perhaps my question was poorly worded but what I was asking: what language / framework do you use for your website, what do you mean by "where any user can hypothetically visit a URL, and the calculator is there, running, and ready for user interaction by multiple users" etc. In Azure there are many ways to host your website, it depends on technologies/languages your website uses. The most generic way is to host it in a VM.

Comment: Alex, I get it. My fault, completely. The website was not in question - it is the program written in C that we offer as a download. That is the only reason I pointed you to the site. The actual question was Instead of having users download the .exe/application and run it on their local machines - could I theoretically run that program on a web server 24/7 and anyone who visits a public URL to that web server could use the program as a "SaaS type of scenario. Essentially, I wanted to use an old .exe as a modern SaaS solution. Hope that helps. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

> - Is what I describe possible?

Well, If you are talking about a pure command-line application: yes.

But, If you are talking about a GUI application: If your application not fully usable from the command line, Go back to the source code and strip down all windows, buttons, UI stuff, etc.. AND **make it usable from the command line**.

> - Will I need Azure?

Any cloud provider will do just fine. Depending on the traffic, an old laptop with an internet connection might be enough for your case.

> - What exactly in Azure will I need (i.e. which products/resources)?

Azure virtual machine with a publicly accessible IP.

> - Do I need to use the compiled/decompiled version?
> - Will we need to change any code in the .exe to make this work?
> - What do I not know that I should know?

## Using decompiled version (Source code):

### WebAssembly

> WebAssembly is a new type of code that can be run in modern web browsers — it is a low-level assembly-like language with a compact binary format that runs with near-native performance and provides languages such as C/C++, C# and Rust with a compilation target so that they can run on the web. It is also designed to run alongside JavaScript, allowing both to work together.

### Emscripten

> Compile C and C++ code, or any other language that uses LLVM, into WebAssembly, and run it on the Web, Node.js, or other wasm runtimes.

## Using compiled verison (executable):

### Common Gateway Interface-ish approach

> Common Gateway Interface (CGI) is an interface specification for web servers to execute programs like console applications (also called command-line interface programs) running on a server that generates web pages dynamically. Such programs are known as CGI scripts or simply as CGIs. The specifics of how the script is executed by the server are determined by the server. In the common case, a CGI script executes at the time a request is made and generates HTML.

My suggestion would be to use python, PHP or any scripting language you are familiar with to spin up a webserver and execute command based on incoming requests.

Python example:

```py
import subprocess
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/calculator') # Accessible from http://[ipaddress]:[port]/calculator
def hello_RedPanda():
    command = "..." # as if you are running your program from cmd.
    result = subprocess.check_output(command) # execute given command
    return result # to your web browser
```

Once you are done with all the back-end pluming, you can add your buttons and tabs back by rebuilding your UI on the client-side using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Building the UI in client-side is actually the easy part. The really tricky part in your case is (as I mentioned above) making your application usable from the command line.

## See more:

1. [WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly)
2. [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/introducing_emscripten/about_emscripten.html)
3. [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)
4. [A case similar to yours](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/2igpfy/confused_can_you_embed_a_simple_c_program_into_a/)

Comment: Wow. Speechless. Thank you so much. I know a lot of people would say "Google it" but I have, and it is difficult to ask Google something when you are not sure of the parameters of your own question. You, sir, understood completely. Unfortunately, it would seem, this is not as simple as I first thought. I assumed there was no difference in someone running the program locally, or letting it run on a virtual machine for all to use so each individual would not have to download locally. In theory, I hope, I didn't seem idiotic. You are very appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: And in case I didn't mention it enough - THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @RedPanda you're welcome :). what your are trying to do is a really good step in favor of increasing the shelf-life of your application and make it accessible to different devices. please don't be intimidated by all the complexity of the process. if you have the source code, it's smooth sail from there. Good luck in your journey.

Comment: I do have the source code, so your comment makes me feel much, much better. I will learn along the way. I am definitely out of my comfort zone - I am a LAMP/Front end designer with very basic PHP experience. A new challenge. Thank you for the kind words, have a wonderful rest of your year!